# How to run php file from Arduino ethernet shield

Tags: php, arduino, xampp

I am running a PHP file From Arduino, I want to update a table in the database but not able to run a PHP file from Arduino.

I tried to write an Arduino code that shown below

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDA, 0x02 };
char serverName[] = "192.168.0.162";
int serverPort = 80;

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
while(true);
} else {
Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}
 delay(1000);
 }

void loop() {
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   String incoming = Serial.readString();
   Serial.println(incoming);
   insertToDb(incoming);
 }
}

void insertToDb(String value) {
  String postData = "value=" + value;
  Serial.println(postData);

  Serial.println("connecting...");
   if (client.connect(serverName, serverPort)) {
   Serial.println("connected");
   client.print("GET /localhost/par/api/update.php");
   client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
   client.print("Host: ");
   client.println(serverName);
   client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
   client.println("Connection: close");
   client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
   client.print("Content-Length: ");
   client.println(postData.length());
   client.println();
   client.println(postData);
   Serial.println("insert conplete");
   } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }

 client.stop();
 }
```

Here I am running localhost(XAMPP) want to run a PHP file. Running a PHP file from Arduino but the problem is PHP file is not executing from Arduin. The Problem arrives itself the file not running from Arduino. Anyone Expert in Arduino please suggest me to debug code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Anyone knows please help me guys

Comment: guys anyone?????

Comment: What debugging have you tried so far? Does your `insertToDb` function run when you send serial data?

Comment: 1) You only posted the question 3 hours ago and your expecting an answer, be patient! 2) You are getting the uri `/localhost/`, does this actually belong in here? It doesn't seem correct. 3) What have you done to debug? Did you check your HTTP logs on the server?